# Simple ActionListener within a 2D array of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, multidimensional-array, jtogglebutton

Okay so I am making a 2d array of JToggleButtons. I got the action listener up and going, but I have no way to tell which button is which.

If I click one, all it returns is something like

> javax.swing.JToggleButton[,59,58,19x14,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@53343ed0,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=]

Is there anyway to stick some sort of item or number in the button object to associate each button? 
And then when the button is clicked I can retrieve that item or number that was given to it?

Here is my button generator code. (How could I make "int l" associate (and count) to each button made, when it is called, it will return that number, or something along those lines.

```
JToggleButton buttons[][] = new JToggleButton[row][col];
int l = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JToggleButton("");
                buttons[i][j].setSize(15,15);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new e());
                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
                l++;

            }
        }
```

ActionListner

```
public class e implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        System.out.println(source);
    }

}
```

variable "source" is what I use to get my data, so how can int l, be returned through "source" (as its unique value for the unique button clicked) as a button is clicked?

Thanks,
-Austin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simple way is add ClientProperty to the JComponent, add to your definition into loop e.g.

```
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("column", i);
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("row", j);
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

rename `e` to the `MyActionListener` and change its contents

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JToggleButton btn = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
                + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row"));
}
```

EDIT:

for `MinerCraft` clone isn't required to implements ony of [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), there is only about [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), find out that in this code (don't implement any of Listeners anf remove used ItemListener)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonsIcon extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ButtonsIcon t = new ButtonsIcon();
            }
        });
    }

    public ButtonsIcon() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 4, 4));

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setBorder(null);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setIcon((errorIcon));
        button.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        button.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        button.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        add(button);

        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setBorderPainted(false);
        button1.setBorder(null);
        button1.setFocusable(false);
        button1.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button1.setIcon((errorIcon));
        button1.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        button1.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        button1.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        add(button1);
        button1.setEnabled(false);

        final JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton();
        toggleButton.setIcon((errorIcon));
        toggleButton.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        toggleButton.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (toggleButton.isSelected()) {
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
        add(toggleButton);

        final JToggleButton toggleButton1 = new JToggleButton();
        toggleButton1.setIcon((errorIcon));
        toggleButton1.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        toggleButton1.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton1.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (toggleButton1.isSelected()) {
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
        add(toggleButton1);
        toggleButton1.setEnabled(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: be sure that there are another two ways (AFAIK) how to do it correctly, maybe you have to wait

Comment: Okay another question. I have this added on.
if (bombloc == true) {
     buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("bomb", true);
    } else {
     buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("bomb", false);
    }

How do I check to see if its true, I know I can click it and it says true, but how do I make an "if" statement via the btn.getClientProperty?

Comment: Nevermind I got that too work. I guess I just have one last question with how the actionListener is working. I have imageicons for stuff, how do I get the current btn (if its a bomb) to display the bomb symbol? I got it say if its a bomb and the imagecons are all loaded, I just don't know how to get the icon to update I.E. btn.setIcon(bombimage); <- that says the variable is nonexistent since its in the engine class.

Comment: @Austin for MineCraft clone isn't necessary to implement ActionListener, there you have to only setIcon and to check if isSelected, please see my edit

Comment: ok, I get that and I have it working. And now I have another question I am searching for, how do I register a "rick-click". We have to use that to lay down our flags on minesweeper.

Comment: would I just add this to the MyActionListener I created then? like...in the same class? Or make a new class?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the row and column data to each listener. You could add an explicit constructor, but I suggest adding a little method (which may have more added to it later).

```
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(e(i, j));
...
private ActionListener e(final int i, final int j) {
    return new ActionListener() {
        // i and j available here
        ...
```

(In JDK8 you should be able to use a lambda to reduce the syntax clutter.)

And then renaming it with a better name.

Answer (score 0):

I made a minesweeper game and ran into a similar problem. One of the only ways you can do it, is to get the absolute location of the clicked button, then divide that by the x and y between buttons, so for me it was

```
if ((e.getComponent().getX() != (randx) * 25 && e.getComponent().getY() != (randy) * 25) &&bomb[randx][randy] == false) {
```

This code was to check if the area had bombs. So I had 25 x and y difference between location of bombs. That will just give you a general idea on how to do this.

I believe: (x - x spacing on left side) / buffer - 1 would work.

Comment: I am doing minesweeper too! But isn't there something simpler to just label each button with? (in the background that is)

Comment: Well, besides that one, you can go through a list of all the buttons and compare it to the Component, if it lines up you are in. The major problem is, the mouse-clicked point is relevant to the component clicked, not the full Frame, so you have to get the component to make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'e.getSource()' you can always call 'e.getActionCommand()'. For each button you can specify this by:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Specify your parameters here"); /*you get these from getActionCommand*/
button.setText("title here"); /*as far as I remember*/
```

Comment: what I meant is that you these parameters are replied to getActionCommand() method for the specified ActionListener instance

Comment: But that adds text to the buttons, I want them to be blank. This is a minesweeper game.