# How to draw a colored rectangle on a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm going to enhance an application with a Swing UI, to allow the user to pick colors so they're not stuck with the default color choices.

It is common for other applications to have shaded rectangles drawn on each button that activates a color selector, with the rectangle's color changing accordingly when a new color is selected.  I am trying to achieve the same effect by placing a small JPanel with the selected color on the button, but that results in a tiny square in the middle of the button, instead of filling most of the surface of the button.

I figure another way would be to dynamically generate  rectangular icons with the colors and then add the appropriate icon to each button, but surely there must be a simpler way?

Comment: Since there is no way of making a custom renderer for the buttons, I don't think it will be very easy. But I guess you could always make a custom button (say, ColourButton). Otherwise your solution with the icons seems pretty nice.

Comment: Have you tried setBackground(Color) on the Button (make sure the button is opaque with setOpaque(boolean))?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `setBackground()` but it only changes the color in a rectangle surrounding the button, it doesn't change the surface color of the button.

Answer (score 3):

put there `JButton.setIcon` with expected `Rectangle`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9300813/714968)

EDIT

> I am trying to achieve the same effect by placing a small JPanel with the selected color on the button, but that results in a tiny square in the middle of the button, instead of filling most of the surface of the button.

only `JFrame (BorderLayout)` and `JPanel (FlowLayout)` have got pre-implemented `LayoutManager`, for rest of `JComponents` (add one `JComponent` to the another `JComponent`) you have to define `LayoutManager`, [please read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140922/714968)

Comment: I think this approach would not only be more robust than setting the BG as suggested in other answers, but would also be more like the user experience 'the path of least surprise' the OP is after.  Lovely little addition by @trashgod, though I'm still undecided between using an `Icon` and altering the `Graphics` of a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Good points. I'll implement `Icon` when I want to leverage a component's text alignment; a `BufferedImage` is handy for compositing.

Comment: I ended up using the technique in the ColorIcon example to draw a filled rectangle icon on each button.  I didn't realize it would be that simple. Trashgod, if you rewrite your ColorIcon comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using setBackground that works for me:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
        button.setOpaque(true);
        panel.add(button);
        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(button, "Choose a color", button.getBackground());
                if (c != null) {
                    button.setBackground(c);
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: While the code above works for the default Look and Feel, with the Windows Look and Feel it doesn't work as intended; it only shows a red rectangle surrounding the button and the surface color of the button does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Every swing component is drawn using the JComponent.drawComponent(...) method, you can override the default behavior if you want. For example, to make a panel like you suggest. It is worth noting though, that you can change a jpanels background color to achieve the exact same thing.

```
    JColorChooser chooser = new JColorChooser(Color.BLACK);
    chooser.setVisible(true);

    Color color = chooser.getColor();
    if (color!=null) {
        colorPanel.setBackground(color);
    }
```

Where colorPanel would be your JPanel indicating your color.