# Individually Identifying JButtons in a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I have been creating a system by which I am listing various seats on a train within a GUI. I had decided to use a simple grid layout with numbered JButtons representing the seats and the seatNo and empty JLabels to represent empty space (I realise this may be trivial but it was simple). I have used a Gridlayout and I have created the Buttons and Labels as shown below.

I have an List (compArray2) in a separate class that consists of 0s and 1s and a direction that represent where there should be a seat and where the shouldn't be a seat. the .getNum gets the value either 0 for empty space or 1 for a seat and the .getDir gets the direction the seat will be facing.

```
public JPanel rowPanelCreation(int type, int rowNo, int width){

    theNoOfSeats=0;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,width));

    List<seatLayout> layout = new ArrayList<>();
    layout = ModelConstants.compArray2;


    for (seatLayout isit : x2){

        buttonEna = new JButton();
            buttonEna.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD , 14));
            buttonEna.setBorderPainted(false);
        buttonDis = new JLabel();

        if (isit.getNum()==0){
            if (isit.getDir()=='x'){
            panel.add(buttonDis);
            }
        }

        else if (isit.getNum()==1){

            theNoOfSeats++;

            if (isit.getDir()=='N'){
                image = new ImageIcon("/Users/Tomousee/NetBeansProjects/SortedList/src/Resources/chairDefaultN.png"); 
                buttonEna.setIcon(image);
                buttonEna.setText(String.valueOf(ModelConstants.compSeatNo.get(theNoOfSeats)));
                buttonEna.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                buttonEna.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                panel.add(buttonEna);
                }
            else if (isit.getDir()=='E'){
                image = new ImageIcon("/Users/Tomousee/NetBeansProjects/SortedList/src/Resources/chairDefaultE.png");
                buttonEna.setIcon(image);
                buttonEna.setText(String.valueOf(ModelConstants.compSeatNo.get(theNoOfSeats)));
                buttonEna.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                buttonEna.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                buttonEna.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have chosen : ");}});
                panel.add(buttonEna);
                }
            else if (isit.getDir()=='S'){
                image = new ImageIcon("/Users/Tomousee/NetBeansProjects/SortedList/src/Resources/chairDefaultS.png");
                buttonEna.setIcon(image);
                buttonEna.setText(String.valueOf(ModelConstants.compSeatNo.get(theNoOfSeats)));
                buttonEna.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                buttonEna.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                panel.add(buttonEna);
                }
            else if (isit.getDir()=='W'){
                image = new ImageIcon("/Users/Tomousee/NetBeansProjects/SortedList/src/Resources/chairDefaultW.png");
                buttonEna.setIcon(image);
                buttonEna.setText(String.valueOf(ModelConstants.compSeatNo.get(theNoOfSeats)));
                buttonEna.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                buttonEna.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                panel.add(buttonEna);
                }
        }
    }
    return panel;
}
```

the main problem I am having is that when I press one of the seat buttons I want a message to appear telling me the seatNo of the seat I have selected is. However when I do this it simply displays the very last seatNo. Is there a better way I could do this ? I'm assuming that as all the buttons are fundamentally the same, there is no way to differentiate between them ?

Comment: All this code does is creates the buttons. If you're having trouble with some action, wouldn't it be relevant to show your `actionPerformed`? Or is this where you think the error is occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"I want a message to appear telling me the seatNo of the seat I have selected is. However when I do this it simply displays the very last seatNo."*

Here's your problem. It's a reference problem. In the end, all the buttons will have the same `JButton` and `JLabel` reference. So all the buttons and labels will get the *last* button and label reference created, hence *"displays the very last seatNo."*

```
buttonEna = new JButton();
buttonEna.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD , 14));
buttonEna.setBorderPainted(false);
buttonDis = new JLabel();
```

You need to create a new `JButton` and new `JLabel` reference each iteration

```
JBUtton buttonEna = new JButton();
buttonEna.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD , 14));
buttonEna.setBorderPainted(false);
JLabel buttonDis = new JLabel();
```

---

Another approach would be to have an array of `JButton`, loop to set the buttons, and add them to the `Panel`. Say you have a `GridLayout(2, 2)`. You then would need a array of 4 `JButton`s

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
...
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD , 14));
    buttonEna.setBorderPainted(false);
    // set other properties for button
    panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Comment: [nicer and easier by putClientPropery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300813/714968)